# Infopath attachment field is not working in send email workflow

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, infopath

I have created an InfoPath form which has an attachment field. I also have a send email workflow. I have attachment field attached to email, however when the email is sent, attachment is not shown on the email. It shows True. However, other field such as (Assigned from) is shown on the email. I don't understand why

[image]

Comment: @Mohamed El-Qassas MVP, I have clarified my question

Comment: Great, the question reopened again   :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of this field "Attachments" is Boolean. It determines whether the current item has attachments or not.

To retrieve the attachment files that are attached to a list item in the workflow, we need to call REST API:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(current item id)/AttachmentFiles/
```

Working with files attached to list items by using REST:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#FileAttachments

How to call REST API to get attachments in the SharePoint Designer workflow:

https://sshareasolutions.com/2017/09/20/sharepoint-list-attachment-url-in-email-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow-and-rest-api/